# When to use Account vs. AccountChangeEvent

Tags: trigger, account

I'm playing around with creating a Apex Trigger for a use case where after a change has been committed on an Account sObject, it sends a Json of the `Trigger.new` to a HTTP Endpoint.

I've used `Account` for now and works as expected but I was pointed to `AccountchangeEvent` for this use case however once I update a field inside an Account, it is not shown in the debug logs so I don't think it triggered. Also it only seems to support `after insert`. So when should you actually use `AccountChangeEvent` and when is it best to stick with just `Account` for an apex trigger?

Comment: My advice would be to check https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture and https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro, that will explain it in nice and clear way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AccountChangeEvent` is a Platform Event, specifically a [Change Data Capture](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/understand-change-data-capture) (CDC) trigger. It's always "after insert" because we're handling an `AccountChangeEvent` Platform Event object, not the `Account` itself. This CDC event triggers whenever an Account is inserted, updated, deleted, or undeleted. It can be directly subscribed to by Platform Event clients, as well, such as a third-party Enterprise Service Bus. Because this event occurs *after* the transaction finalizes, you won't see it in the same log as the transaction that inserted/updated/deleted/undeleted the Account itself. Also, this event always runs as the *Automated User*, rather than the user that actually performed the DML operation.

You should use the `Account` trigger when you need synchronous code. Validating data, preventing deletion, performing immediate field updates, etc on the `Account` itself must be done in an `Account` trigger. Other types of updates, such as updating related Contacts or Cases, *can* be serviced by an `AccountChangeEvent`, but you might find it less efficient than directly handling such changes in the `Account` object itself. If you're doing a callout or other non-critical asynchronous updates, the CDC trigger can be a great option to reduce governor limit usage in the synchronous trigger part of your business logic.

Comment: Because AccountChangeEvent is asynchronous, it can avoid performance issues where a synchronous trigger is not needed.